# Як перекласти українською «творожный сыр»?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Російський термін «творожный сыр». В даному разі мова йде про різновид сиру, що виготовляється з кисломолочного сиру або подібним способом, без визрівання та з участю молочнокислих бактерій. Чи є в питомій лексиці української мови слово на позначення такого продукту?

Comment: Можна вточнити — а як відрізняються «творожный сыр» і звичайний «творог»? І ще: а «[cream cheese](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_cheese)»/«[сливочный сыр](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сливочный_сыр)»/«[вершковий сир](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Вершковий_сир)» — це часом не те?

Comment: Sasha, користувач begemothus нижче люб’язно дав посилання на сайт, яким я скористалася ще раніше, перш ніж звернутися сюди:). Зацитовую джерело:

«Разница между правильным сливочным сыром и творожным сыром заключается в том, что они производятся из разного сырья и имеют разные органолептические показатели, в том числе и консистенцию. И что бы ни писали на упаковке, необходимо смотреть состав продукта. Правильный сливочный сыр производится из сливок, творожный — из творога или мягкого сыра. Фантазийное наименование продукта не всегда правильно отражает его суть».

Comment: Також про різницю між сиром і «творожным сыром»:
«Творожный сыр, согласно нашему ГОСТу, — это "молочный или молочный составной продукт, произведенный из молока и/или продуктов переработки молока по технологии мягкого сыра без созревания или творога с последующей термической обработкой, и/или взбиванием, и/или аэрированием или без них, с добавлением или без добавления молочных продуктов, пищевкусовых продуктов и немолочных компонентов (за исключением консервантов, немолочных жиров и немолочных белков) с массовой долей молочного белка не менее 6%"».
Отже, м'який сир — сировина в даному разі.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, чи є таке слово, але можу запропонувати
**Кисломолочний сир**.

Така думка народилася звідси

(мовою оригіналу)

> И поскольку главным сырьем является мягкий сыр или творог, то готовый
> продукт имеет характерный кисломолочный вкус с привкусом наполнителя,
> если таковой используют.

https://eda.ru/media/vopros/chem-slivochnyy-syr-otlichaetsya-ot-tvorozhnogo

Comment: begemothus, річ у тім, що «кисломолочний сир» — це «творог», а не «творожный сыр». Про «творог» ми українською кажемо: м’який сир, домашній сир (особисто я уникаю цього словосполучення, оскільки твердий сир також може бути домашнім), кисломолочний сир.

Comment: *це «творог», а не «творожный сыр»* - ???

Comment: *кисломолочний сир* - Да? Жодного разу не чув такого. Я спробував перевести за сенсом викладеного за посиланням. Але якщо наплутав - вибачте )))

Comment: @Sasha дякую....

Comment: Так! У чому полягає Ваше питання? Кисломолочний сир — це власне «творог» російською.

Comment: Так, варто резюмувати.
Кисломолочний сир (сир м’який) — це «творог».
Вершковий сир відрізняється, як ми з’ясували, від «творожного» типом сировини. М’який (кисломолочний) сир виконує роль основи для виготовлення «творожного» сиру.
Тепер потрібно шукати укр.відповідник саме терміну «творожный сыр».

Comment: *Кисломолочний сир — це власне «творог» російською.*  - https://translate.google.ru/?sl=ru&tl=uk&text=%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3&op=translate  Саме так я завжди вважав

Comment: Ха, адже ви маєте рацію. Тепер пишуть на упаковках "кисломолочний". Років п'ятдесят тому цього не було. Писали просто "сир". А більш пізні часи я вже не бачив так близько.

Comment: @Ольга, насправді «м'який сир» — доволі багатозначне словосполучення (дехто взагалі наводить його як синонім вершковому, причому як [українською](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Вершковий_сир), так і [російською](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сливочный_сир)). Тобто після уважного читання посилання «чем сливочный сыр отличается от творожного» (у якому, до речі, «творожный сыр» визначається через російські ГОСТи, а про «сливочный» сказано, що це не чітко визначене поняття — тобто теоретично українською може й не бути точних еквівалентів) мені здається, що і _м'який сир_ є широким поняттям, у яке входить…

Comment: …і «творожный», і «сливочный», і, можливо, навіть інші (зокрема, [ньошатель](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ньошатель) і [брі](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Брі_(сир)) в англійській вікіпедії вважаються різновидами soft cheese). Тобто мені здається, поняття _м'який сир_ цілком містить те, що Вам треба — але містить і зайве (але поки в мене немає думок щодо точнішого еквівалента).

Comment: Sasha, мені подобається Ваша думка, візьму на озброєння! Можливо, про кисломолочний продукт краще казати: «сир кисломолочний» (не «м’який»), термін «м’який сир» присвоїти власне різновидам вершкового і т.д. сиру, так званим soft cheese, а оцей капосний «творожный сыр» як конкретний вид назвати «м’який кисломолочний сир» — те, що наразі ми кажемо про «творог»? Це було б комфортно.